# Unable to run Firebird

Tags: windows-7, firebird

I am installing Firebird (v1.5.5 - I know it's old but it works) on a new computer which is running Windows 7. I have installed the classic server version as a service. According to documentation at the Firebird site, I modified the firebird.conf file so that IPCName would be global\FirebirdIPI; I did this while the service was not running.

Despite all my efforts, I have been unable to access any of the databases which I copied to this new computer via ISQL. FWIW, the EMS SQL 2005 manager program is successful in accessing the databases, but this program apparently has a direct method which does not require fbclient.dll.

What else should I be checking?

---

Update from a few days later. After wasting a great deal of time with Windows 7, we decided to downgrade the computer and run XP. After installing the superserver version of FB 1.5.5, I can run my programs and access the databases which are stored *on this computer*. Attempts to access the databases from other computers connected on the network failed with a variety of error messages, but normally something like 'i/o error for file !firebird!\db\q400.fdb'.

In order to allow people on the network to continue to access the databases, I revived the NT server and started the Firebird service - and all the programs can access these databases successfully from remote computers!

To simplify matters, there are three computers on the network:

1. the NT server ('zorcomp'), which is running the Firebird service; the fdb files reside on this computer in a directory called 'db' which sits under a shared directory called 'firebird'
2. a computer running XP, called 'kivserver', which also has a shared directory called 'firebird' and underneath that a directory called 'programs'. Copies of all the fdb files reside in a directory called 'db'.
3. a computer running XP, which maps \zorcomp\firebird to disk L: and \kivserver\firebird to disk T. From this computer, I can run a program sitting in T:\programs and get it to access successfully a file sitting in L:\db. If I stop the FB service on zorcomp and start the same service on kivserver, the same program cannot access files sitting in T:\db.

I hope this is clear enough. For the life of me, I can't see any difference between all the files which are residing in \kivserver\firebird to those which are sitting in \zorcomp\firebird - but somehow there is a difference!

## Obviously, I don't want this arrangement to continue - the NT server has to be retired honourably.

Further edit. I now have the firebird server running on 'kivserver' (NT). I can access the database files locally.

Computers running Win7 can now access these database files using a connection string \\kivserver\firebird\db\database.fdb.

Computers running XP cannot access these database files, although IIRC wisql did succeed with \\kivserver\firebird\db\database.db.

The NT server has been disconnected from the network.
TIA,
No'am

Comment: Despite my answer, I want to say I'm using Firebird 2.1 in windows 7 and never touched anything to make it work... are you sure you still want to use Firebird 1.5?  I'm sure you can open Firebird 1.5 files (ODS) directly with Firebird 2, but I have no one to test.

Comment: What I really want is that my programs (written in Delphi) can access the databases. They use a component which works with Firebird 1.5.

Comment: @jachguate, although that might work it is preferrable not to open lower ODS files with higher Firebird versions to avoid possible corruptions. The best thing you can do is to use the gbak utility in its 1.5 version to back up the database and restore it with the gbak 2.0 to get a 2.0 database file.

Comment: @No'am Newman, this is off-topic but you might consider to use the Zeos components. They are free, developed with Delphi and work nice with Firebird 2.0 and 2.1.

Comment: @No'am Newman: Which component is it? are you sure it can't connect to Firebird 2.x?

Comment: @Guillem Vicens: Thanks, I know the backup/restore procedure to update the ODS... I was just making suggestions with no known of the real need here.  On the other hand, I have never seen a corrupted database file when a new engine opens a **supported** ODS file from a previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several months later, the NT server was somewhat abruptly retired when it displayed 'MBR error' on rebooting after someone unlugged it by accident. Thus I was left with no option but to start running the Firebird server program on 'kivserver'. The connection problems returned.

Eventually I was able to solve the problem with the following connection string

> 10.0.0.202:e:\firebird\db\manager.fdb

where 10.0.0.202 is the ip address of the server, and e:\firebird\db the directory in which the database sits, relative to the server itself.

I hope that someone else, some time, will find this information useful.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK EMS SQL uses fbclient.dll (or a wraper around it).

If the only thing you want is to access the databases, I suggest you to do so using TCP protocol instead of the local protocol.  To do it connect like this:

```
c:\>isql localhost:c:\path\to\db.fdb -u sysdba -p masterkey
```

Unless you're avoiding TCP or the machine have no local interface enabled, it will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to connect to your database:

hostname:drive:\complete path\filename.fdb

or

\hostname\drive\complete path\filename.fdb

May I know the component you're using?

Comment: I tried this yesterday with no success. When using the string 't:\db\q400.fdb' (the file's location is in directory 'db' of the network disk mapped as 't' on the local computer), the error message was 'i/o error for file '\!firebird!\db\q400.fdb'. When using the string '\kivserver\firebird\db\q400.fdb' (ie \hostname\drive\complete path\filename.fdb), the result was 'unknown database'. I am trying both my own programs (using dbExpress components) and a program called 'mywisql' which probably does the same.

Comment: @No'am Newman: Firebird database file must be local to the server. It is in the documentation, I just don't have a handle to it now.

Answer (score 0):

If your clients are Windows 7 then you might try to use **\\hostname\sharename\filename.fdb** instead of **drive:\filename.fdb** connection string.